# URL fragment removed by update panel

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

**My Problem:**

I use IE8 for testing.

I create a simple aspx page(mypage.aspx) having an updatepanel with a button (button1) in it.
When page loaded i use javascript to add a fragment to window.location

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "#myfragment";
//Window address bar will be: http://mydomain.com/mypage.aspx#myfragment
```

Then i click button1, mypage update successfully. But in address bar myfragment is removed

```
//Window address bar will be: http://mydomain.com/mypage.aspx#
```

**My Question:**

What things happened? How can i remain myfragment when click button1?

**Note:** This problem occurs only in IE8, Firefox and google chrome work fine.

***Thanks for any answer...***

Comment: exactly at which point are you executing the above javascript?

Comment: what _exactly_ does your update button 1 do? Is it inside a form?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a post back, the server completely rebuilds the page. Unless you have ensured that any element of the page that is entered by the user, is maintained in view state, then the user entered information will not be carried in the data returned when the page is posted back

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx - page life cycle

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx - view state

will help - its a learning curve - but can be very wothwhile